# talend convert data in a relational database to turtle

Tags: rdf, talend

I just started exploring Talend Open Studio Data Integration. I am interested in using Talend to convert data in a relational database to Turtle. For example, suppose I have record in an electronic dental record system like this:

```
patient_id 1001
tooth_num 1
procedure D2740 (porcelain crown)
procedure_date 1/1/2017
```

I want to convert this record into a number of Turtle statements that look something like this:

```
@prefix : <http://example.com/>
:patient_1001 a :Patient .
:tooth_1 a :Molar .
:tooth_1 :part_of :patient_1001 .
:procedure_D2740 a :Porcelain_Crown_Procedure .
:procedure_D2740 :procedure_date "2017-01-10"^^xsd:datetime .
:procedure_D2740 :restores :tooth_1 .
```

Typically, I write a computer program to do this. However, I would like to speed up the process of creating this transformation code. Can I do such things in Talend?

Thanks.

Comment: check out the tMap component.  I think it will help you based on your example.